# Random exception Resources$NotFoundException in MediaRouteButton

Tags: android, android-jetpack

Recently I started to get a few random reports of this error on google play vitals:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
  An error occurred while executing doInBackground() (AsyncTask.java:354)
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
  Drawable drawable/mr_button_light_static with resource ID #0x7f080195
  ...
  android.content.res.XResources.getDrawable (XResources.java:770)
  androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton$RemoteIndicatorLoader.doInBackgroundd
  androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton$RemoteIndicatorLoader.doInBackground
  ...
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
  Drawable (missing name) with resource ID #0x7f08012b
```

It seems to come from this code in MediaRouteButton:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-mediarouter-release/mediarouter/mediarouter/src/main/java/androidx/mediarouter/app/MediaRouteButton.java#812

```
        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Drawable.ConstantState remoteIndicatorState = sRemoteIndicatorCache.get(mResId);
            if (remoteIndicatorState == null) {
                return mContext.getResources().getDrawable(mResId);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

So at first I was blaming R8 resource shrinking, but inspecting the .aab bundle I was able to find the file under `res/drawable/mr_button_light_static.xml` with valid xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_mr_button_connected_30_light"
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_mr_button_disconnected_light"
        android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_mr_button_disabled_light"/>
</selector>
```

Something weird is that it's only happening in a few Pixel 3 devices (Pixel 3a and Pixel 3 XL, Android 9)

I already tried excluding this file from R8 shrinker, but as I said, the file is correctly bundled. So I'm wondering if this might be some issue with the APK that google plays generates for those devices? Any suggestion?

I'm currently using this version of mediarouter:

```
implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.2.3'
```

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Comment: Not really, eventually I gave up and I haven't seen it again.

Comment: Well I talked too soon, happened again in a Nexus 5X Android 8.1.0, I'll try copying the resource from the library directly into my drawable dir and see if that helps.